# HTML to PDF Causing issues With Japense Character

Tags: node.js, html-pdf

I am creating a  pdf file with node module html-pdf. Its working fine locally.

The only porblem which i am getting that its not displaying Japenese character in pdf generated on  Live ubuntu server.

On Localhost its displaying.

Japenese character for example 請求書

Any help will be really appreciable here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the fonts with JP lang support on live Ubuntu server it starts working.